# Null assignment behavior java

Tags: java, eclipse

my date format changes according to certain conditions, in order to have global access I initialize them and then assign a value according to condition.

But looking at De-bugger these values are not being re-assigned, they remain null as per initialization.

I am new to java what is the assignment behavior that is causing this ?

Here's code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df     = null;
        SimpleDateFormat df2    = null;
        SimpleDateFormat date_c = null;
        SimpleDateFormat t      = null;
        SimpleDateFormat t2     = null;
        SimpleDateFormat df5    = null;
        SimpleDateFormat df3    = null;

        if ( make == "NCR")
        {
        df     = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        df2    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        date_c = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        t      = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        t2     = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        df5    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        df3    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        }

        else if ( make == "WINCORE")
        {
            df     = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
            df2    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
            date_c = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            t      = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
            t2     = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
            df5    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
            df3    = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssS");
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: If you really debugged through this, you'd see neither of the branches being executed - indicating that it's got nothing to do with assignment, and everything to do with string equality comparisons.

Comment: I don't see why you need all those date formats.  You create 7 instances when 4 would do just fine.  And I'd make all of them static & final; I'd also set lenient to false for all.

Comment: @duffymo I can see a need for it in terms of modifiability - if you want to change one of them, it's simpler to just have to change it here rather than having to create a new variable for it since there was only 4 variables. However, just assigning one to the other should work - i.e. `t2 = df2` (unless this is what you meant).

Comment: what is the value of your make variable ?

Comment: I'd just create one DateFormat per format and reuse it.  If I wanted a new one, I'd create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because neither of two conditions fulfils. You use `==` for String comparison, and this is most likely an error. `==` compares objects *identity* and strings are objects. For value-based comparsion you should use `equals`. Putting literal to the left gives you a `null`-safe comparison (it is a common Java idiom): `"NCR".equals(make)`. But you can also use `make.equals("NCR")` if `make` is not `null` or you want `NullPointerException` for `null` `make`.

Compare the following:

```
assert "NCR" == "NCR" : "String literals are interned, so they have the same identity";
assert "NCR" != new String("NCR") : "String with the same value but not the same identity"; 
assert "NCR".equals(new String("NCR")) : "But they are equal";
```

Comment: Please use `make.equals("NCR")` instead of the other way around (unless `make` can be `null`). We don't use `1 == i` or say `1 equals to i` and this is the same as doing that.

Comment: When you use "==" to compare two Strings, Java won't compare the value of those strings, but their identities. If you want to compare their value, use  make.equals("WINCORE") instead.

Comment: well it depends on how you define make. if you define make as ` String make = "NCR";` then ` make == "NCR"` will return true

Comment: @Dukeling "NCR".equals(make) is better than make.equals("NCR") in my view. Since `make.equals("NCR")` can throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: "Yoda" coding.  It's an old C/C++ idiom.  I think it makes sense to do it when you have a static String.

Comment: @chetan If you defined `make` as `String make = "NCR"` you probably shouldn't be using a string. An enum or int would be better IMO.

Comment: int?  No.  I'd rather see "NCR" than 5.  And enum is arguably okay, but this is someone who's new to Java, so I'd say a String is fine for now.

Comment: @duffymo I was thinking something like `static final int NCR = 5`. Arguably an enum is probably better, but I usually find myself needing to hit it with a hammer to get it to work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing strings in java, you do not use `==`, you use `equals()`

```
if ("NCR".equals(make))
 ...
else if ("WINCORE".equals(make))
```

---

Also, put the string literal first, in case that `make` is `null`, so you don't get a `NullPointerException`.